# Puppeteer xpath expression failing, despite valid xpath expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

[image]

I have a page containing the table in the screenshot,which I am trying ro scrape with puppeteer. I can get the table using:

```
    //table[contains(@class, 'table') and .//th[contains(text(), 'Sqft')]]
```

(tested in devtools).

Now I want to get it with puppeteer. I tried:

```
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    try {

        await page.goto(URL).catch(console.error());
        var content = await page.content();
        const codeTableXpath = "//table[contains(@class, 'table') and .//th[contains(text(), 'Sqft')]]"


        const tableHTML = await content.waitForXPath(codeTableXpath).catch(console.error('xpath'));
```

The error is occurring in the last line when I step through the code. How can I grab the table html for further processing?

edit:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`page.content()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecontent) resolves into a string with full HTML contents of the page, while [`waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) is a method of `page`. So you need this (also, `.catch()` requires a function reference or a function expression, not a function call):

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
try {
  await page.goto(URL).catch(console.error); // function reference

  const codeTableXpath =
    "//table[contains(@class, 'table') and .//th[contains(text(), 'Sqft')]]";

  const table = await page.waitForXPath(codeTableXpath) // just page.waitForXPath()
    .catch(() => { console.error('xpath'); }); // function expression

  const tableHTML = await table.evaluate(element => element.outerHTML);
  // or: const tableHTML = await (await table.getProperty('outerHTML')).jsonValue();
```

Comment: When I sent  tableHTML to console.log, I'm getting an elementHandle (please see screenshot). How do I get the tables HTML?

Comment: I've edited the answer. You need to read a bit in the docs how DevTools protocol works, what is `elementHandle` / `JSHandle` in the Node.js (puppeteer) context, and how they relate to the DOM elements / JS values in the browser context.

Comment: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/ - here?

Comment: I think https://github.com/aslushnikov/getting-started-with-cdp/blob/master/README.md + https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md (descriptions of classes at least) may suffice.